# Pacman fork on macOS

Tags: c, macos, makefile, archlinux, package-managers

I’m working on an project, which is a [`pacman`](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/) fork. I’m trying to develop this project for both macOS and Linux. Compiling my project on macOS is so far successful, but I’ve got a problem with some directories. In the Makefile.am, directories for the DB and cache are supposed to be create:.

```
# create the meme DB, cache, makepkg-template and system hook directories upon install
install-data-local:
    for dir in "$(DESTDIR)$(localstatedir)/lib/meme" "$(DESTDIR)$(localstatedir)/cache/meme/pkg" \
               "$(DESTDIR)$(datarootdir)/makepkg-template" "$(DESTDIR)$(datarootdir)/libalpm/hooks"; do \
    test -z "$$dir" || $(MKDIR_P) "$$dir"; \
done
```

Those directories are missing after installation on macOS, so that I get the following error by `pacman`:

```
error: failed to initialize alpm library
(could not find or read directory: /usr/local/Cellar/meme/0.0.8.2/var/lib/meme/)
```

I’m using Homebrew to compile, bottle and install the package manager. You can find my formula on GitHub: https://github.com/kenokenobingo/homebrew-memetap.

Do you have any idea how to get rid of this problem? Is this a OS-specific issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the #archlinux-pacman IRC channel on Freenode (official pacman development channel) pacman installs a couple of empty directories, which seem to be created successfully on a manual `make install` but not when brew does it.

Brew may be deleting these directories because it thinks you don't need them. This is similar to a feature in makepkg too -- if the !emptydirs option is specified in [makepkg.conf(5)](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/makepkg.conf.5.html#_options) or the PKGBUILD, empty directories will be deleted. This option is disabled by default because it can cause issues when those directories are legitimately needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help again! :) #archlinux-pacman are helpful guys and gal!

Comment: Using `brew`, the directories need to be created in `post_install`, see: https://discourse.brew.sh/t/building-a-bottle-how-can-i-stop-brew-from-deleting-directories/2411.